# solving equation (indices/logarithms)

Tags: logarithms

I don't really understand the Logarithms concept when it comes to question with ln or log with base e.for example question like this:

1.solve the equation 
$$x^4\mathrm{e}^{-2\ln(x)}=18-3x$$

Comment: is the equation you want to solve $x^4\mathrm{e}^{-2\ln(x)}=18-3x$? You have a symbol that can not be decoded.

Comment: yes, i've tried but it turned out like that. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

use the property of the logarithm: $a \log x = \log x^a$, and then the definition: $e^{\ln x} = x$